# Android camera freezes after taking one photo

Tags: android, camera, photo

I'm doing one project with camera and after taking one photo camera freezes and u have to finish the activity and recall it again to take another photo, how can I take photo freeze for just 1-2 sec and then surface view to have the camera again. the same for video I am using media recorder, taking video press stop video saves and screen is still alive but I can not take video again I have to restart the activity?

Anybody have a solution?

Comment: @subspider are you using galaxy s to check the camera functionality?

Comment: same problem here. @dsc yeah I'm using a galaxy s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do any image processing in a background `AsyncTask`.  This will allow your UI Activity to continue on and take another picture.

Edit: I cannot delete an accepted answer so please see stoefin's answer below.  Calling `camera.startPreview()` before taking the next photo works for him.

Comment: This is not why the camera is freezing -- stoefln's answer is correct; the preview needs to be restarted.

Answer (score 59):

I found a solution for this: After taking a picture, preview display will have stopped. To take more photos, call `camera.startPreview()` again first.

Comment: just starting the preview did not work for me. However stoping and starting the preview worked as mentioned in the answer below.

Comment: Hey, even if I call `startPreview()` first the camera is not able to open. I would really appreciate it if you helped me out! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47483990/can-only-open-camera-once

Answer (score 17):

after capturing image you should stop the preview and start it back again.

```
mCamera.stopPreview();
mCamera.startPreview();
```

it would work fine.

Comment: Even if I do that, the camera is not able to open. I would really appreciate it if you helped me out! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47483990/can-only-open-camera-once

Answer (score 2):

The camera.startpreview(); answer didn't work for my case  but the code below solved that problem for me and hope it helps others too.I used a thread to delay closing and opening of the camera  after a photo is captured by 500ms

```
 private void start_camera() {
     try {
         camera = Camera.open();
         // camera.lock();
     } catch (RuntimeException e) {
         Log.e(tag, "init_camera: " + e);
         return;
     }
     Camera.Parameters param = camera.getParameters();
     param = camera.getParameters();
     Camera.Size size = param.getSupportedPreviewSizes().get(0);
     param.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
     camera.setParameters(param);
     try {
         camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
         camera.startPreview();
         previewRunning = true;
     } catch (Exception e) {
         Log.e(tag, "init_camera: " + e);
         return;
     }}
 private void captureImage() {
     camera.takePicture(shutterCallback,null,jpegCallback);
     Thread restart_preview=new Thread(){public void run(){
         try {
             Thread.sleep(500);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

         camera.release();
         camera=null;
         start_camera();
     }};
     restart_preview.start();}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the activities defined by the existing camera app on your phone, you can write your own Activity that uses the Camera API directly to accomplish the functionality you describe.  The Camera class is documented here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

Answer (score 0):

The camera is freezing, because you are not restarting the preview of the camera, so restart it by calling `camera.startpreview()`