# How to take two consecutive pictures from camera?

Tags: android, android-camera

When I tried to take a single picture from camera, it works fine. And now I added little bit of modification on my code, and wanna take two consecutive picture from camera.

```
public void takePicture(final boolean isWithFlash) {
    Camera.PictureCallback mCall = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

            if(isWithFlash) {
                savePhotoToDirectory(data, captureImageFileName);

                mCamera.stopPreview();
                mCamera.release();
                mCamera = null;
            } else {
                savePhotoToDirectory(data, captureImageFileName);
                takePicture(true);
            }

        }
    };
    if(mCamera != null) {
        if(!isWithFlash) {
            Parameters param = mCamera.getParameters();
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mCall);
        } else {
            Parameters param = mCamera.getParameters();
            param.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            mCamera.setParameters(param);
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mCall);
        }
    } else {
        Log.d("MYLOG", "Camera is null");
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is take a picture without flash, and then take an another picture with flash consecutively. However, when I tried my code, it only takes first photo, and second `onPictureTaken()` function is not being called.

What am I doing wrong here? Or is there any better way to take two consecutive pictures?

Any comments would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to call `mCamera.stopPreview()` after second call. But you need to call `mCamera.startPreview()` after the first one. I would introduce some delay between two calls to `takePicture()`, e.g. bu using [View.post()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to take the second picture. But maybe this **post** is not necessary, and delay that it causes is too much for your purposes - that's for you to decide.

Comment: Oh, actually I started camera preview in other function, so I had to stop preview after taking picture. Also, using delay was one of my another option, but I'm not sure if it is the best way.

Comment: No, you don't need to stop preview; takePicture does that itself. But you need to restart preview if you want another picture from your camera. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7715021/192373

Comment: Okay, I just tested with `startPreview()` and it seems to be working fine! (I didn't used delay) Thank you so much, you saved my time!