# Android - Camera API takes too much time to capture and save image

Tags: java, android, multithreading, camera

I am trying to use Camera API for my app. When I click take photo button, the UI hangs for about 10 seconds before responding further.

I found a post on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139409/android-camera-freezes-after-taking-one-photo), but the solution wasn't much specific. I think it is a problem of multi-threading. I am a beginner in android development and not proficient with multi-threading.

UploadPrescription.java :

```
package com.example.ayusch.medomo;


import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.ImageFormat;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.media.ExifInterface;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ShareCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Size;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class UploadPrescription extends Fragment {
    private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION = 2;
    private Camera mCamera = null;
    private CameraPreview mCameraPreview;
    private final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 1;
    private FrameLayout preview;
    private File pictureFile;
    private FileOutputStream fos;
    private byte[] byteArray;

    public UploadPrescription() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_upload_prescription, container, false);
        preview = (FrameLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);

        setPreview();

        Button captureButton = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
        captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("ayusch", "inside on click");
                mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
            }

        });
        return root;
    }

    private void setPreview() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                setup();
            } else {

                if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Permission needed to use camera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
            }
        } else {
            setup();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                setup();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Camera Permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
        } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                proceedtowrite();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Storage permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public void setup() {

        mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.set("jpeg-quality", 70);
        parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
        parameters.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
        List<Camera.Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes();
        Camera.Size size = sizes.get(Integer.valueOf((sizes.size() - 1) / 2)); //choose a medium resolution
        parameters.setPictureSize(size.width, size.height);
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCameraPreview = new CameraPreview(getContext(), mCamera);
        preview.addView(mCameraPreview);
    }

    private Camera getCameraInstance() {

        Camera camera = null;
        try {
            camera = Camera.open(0);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // cannot get camera or does not exist
        }
        return camera;
    }

    Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            Log.i("ayusch", "inside onPictureTaken");

            pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();

            if (pictureFile == null) {
                Log.i("ayusch", "Null Picture file, returning...");
                return;
            }
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);

                ////////////////////////////////////
                Bitmap realImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

                ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(pictureFile.toString());

                Log.d("ayusch", exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION));
                if (exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION).equalsIgnoreCase("6")) {
                    realImage = rotate(realImage, 90);
                } else if (exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION).equalsIgnoreCase("8")) {
                    realImage = rotate(realImage, 270);
                } else if (exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION).equalsIgnoreCase("3")) {
                    realImage = rotate(realImage, 180);
                } else if (exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION).equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                    realImage = rotate(realImage, 90);
                }
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                realImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

                ////////////////////////////////////
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        proceedtowrite();
                    } else {

                        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Permission needed to store and upload Prescription", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION);
                    }
                } else {
                    proceedtowrite();
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    };

    public void proceedtowrite() {
        try {
            fos.write(byteArray);
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), PrescriptionUpload.class);
        i.putExtra("prescription", pictureFile);
        startActivity(new Intent(i));
    }

    public static Bitmap rotate(Bitmap bitmap, int degree) {
        int w = bitmap.getWidth();
        int h = bitmap.getHeight();

        Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
        //       mtx.postRotate(degree);
        mtx.setRotate(degree);

        return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, true);
    }

    private static File getOutputMediaFile() {
        Log.i("ayusch", "Getting output media file");
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                "MyCameraApp");
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }
        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                .format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
        Log.i("ayusch", "Filename = " + mediaFile);
        return mediaFile;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            mCameraPreview.getHolder().removeCallback(mCameraPreview);
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
        try {
            mCameraPreview.getHolder().removeCallback(mCameraPreview);
            setPreview();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

CameraPreview.java :

```
package com.example.ayusch.medomo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by Ayusch on 09-Feb-17.
 */
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements
        SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;


    // Constructor that obtains context and camera
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);

        this.mCamera = camera;
        this.mSurfaceHolder = this.getHolder();
        this.mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        this.mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

        try {

            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // left blank for now
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        Log.i("ayusch", "Inside surfaceDestroyed");
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int format,
                               int width, int height) {

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // intentionally left blank for a test
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java :

```
package com.example.ayusch.medomo;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 1;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new UploadPrescription(), "Upload Prescription");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new OrderByName(), "Enter Medicine Name");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new Contact(), "Contact Us");
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }

}
```

Also, during the hang time if I press the button again, app crashes :

```
02-10 19:57:31.481 966-966/com.example.ayusch.medomo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.example.ayusch.medomo, PID: 966
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Camera is being used after Camera.release() was called
                                                                           at android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method)
                                                                           at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1523)
                                                                           at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1468)
                                                                           at com.example.ayusch.medomo.UploadPrescription$1.onClick(UploadPrescription.java:73)
                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5714)
                                                                           at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10926)
                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22589)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

It is due to the line `mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);` in the onClick method of UploadPrescription.java

I have been trying to get my head around it since 2 days without any success. Please Help !!

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what the **PrescriptionUpload** activity is expected to do. At any rate, to make your UI responsive you *must* perform the time-consuming tasks (and your **onPictureTaken()** is a time-consuming task) off the main (UI) thread. **AsyncTask** may be an easy tool for you here. It is strongly recommended to execute **Camera.open()** off the main thread, as well: on some devices, it is reasonably fast, but on others, it may be prohibitively slow.

Comment: Regarding the click while the capture is under way, you should disable the CAPTURE button on click, and enable it again when processing is over.

Comment: So do you mean I need to move my onClick method tasks to AsyncTask ? I mean to say call takePicture method in AsyncTask. Sorry if I sound like a noob ( cause I am : )

Comment: No, don't mess with **onClick()**. **takePicture()** is immediate and only starts an asynchronous process of camera capture. In the end, camera will trigger your **onPictureTaken()**. What you should do, use AsyncTask in onPictureTaken() to do all all processing. Essentially, your **onPictureTaken()** should do only one thing: prepare and call an AsyncTask.

Comment: You should really profile your code and figure out how long everything is taking. Without that we really can't help.

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick and dirty workaround for a similar problem, where I filled the screen with a camera preview and then just captured a screengrab as and when required (responds pretty much immediately) - this actually allowed me to basically film a sequence of frames at a reasonable frame rate.

Hopefully that's enough for you to go on for now. Let me know if not.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand your solution. Could you please mention some more details as to the procedureor something.

Comment: Will reply to you in more detail tomorrow, I will edit my answer, but briefly my solution is to fill the entire screen with a camera preview and then when I want to take an image I just capture what is on the screen immediately - bearing in mind that anything else (any overlay or anything) will also be captured as part of the image. Not ideal, but works for me. Does this sound suitable to you?

Comment: Ok ok....I got your solution, but I need to display actionbar in my activity and hence cannot cover the screen with Camera Preview. Can you suggest something else ?

Comment: Could you temporarily hide the action bar as you take the screengrab and then render it again when the picture is taken?

Comment: I've added a screenshot of task I'm trying to achieve. I cannot hide the actionbar as the camera starts immediately on launch.

Comment: Hmmm, would it be feasible to auto-crop the screen grab to exclude the action bar or are we getting a bit too hacky now?

Answer (score 0):

```
     ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     realImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
     byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

Bitmap#compress is extremely inefficient for PNG format (lack of hardware acceleration etc). Try either resizing the bitmap prior to saving, compressing to JPEG or dumping raw bitmap using native io.